# How to get metadata structure for form fields using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have form,which contains file and textbox

I want metadata in json after  click submit button, is it possible to get metadata such as value, placeholder,id,class etc... such as

```
{"fields":[{"label":"Medical history","field_type":"file","required":true,"field_options":{},"cid":"c14"},{"label":"Firstname","field_type":"text","required":true,"field_options":{"size":"small"},"cid":"c19"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be tedious, but yes, possible. You can use `data-*` attributes to do this. So change each element in your form like:

```
<input type="text" name="medhist"
       data-name="Medical history" data-type="text"
       data-reqd="true" data-field_options="{}"
       data-cid="c14" />
```

Then you can walk through the form elements and collect all the data fields and construct a JSON. Hope this is a right kick-start.

Comment: thanks... but its a dynamic form builder ... is there any way to store source code for generated form in db

Comment: I want the form structure to save in db

Comment: is there any plugin available ?

Comment: What are you currently using now da?

Comment: That's good one. But you need to make the above said changes manually buddy, sorry da! It is you who have to do this!